# Reset Filer not working to my custom module in Magento backend

Tags: magento

In backend, when I click the “Reset Filter” button, it redirects to wrong url and displaying the 404 error.

I don’t know, how to debug this issue.

please help me,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check your store or website base url.